# Customtkinter : how to get the tag_configure of CTkTextbox?

Tags: python-3.x, customtkinter

```
text_all_ko.tag_configure("green", foreground="#587B4A")
text_all_ko.tag_configure("red", foreground="#B33449")

text_all_ko.insert(END,"Task is OK", "green")
text_all_ko.insert(END,"Task is KO", "red")
```

I'm Using Customtkinter
I would like to know if it's possible to get the tag_configure. I need to test if there is red or green inside the CTkTextbox.

Regards

Comment: do you want to insert red and green color text inside textbox? Or do you want to detect if text inside textbox is red or green in color ?

Comment: Hello, I want to detect color indeed.